# How do I drag and drop text in the XCode code editor?

Tags: xcode, macos, user-interface

This is probably something simple. I am coming to XCode from years of using Visual Studio. Say, if I selected some code in the code viewer. How do I drag and drop it from one location to another (in the same code window)?

Comment: What happens when you try to drag selected text?

Comment: @Willeke: it drops whatever is selected and starts a new selection.

Comment: What should happen?

Comment: @Willeke: Do users of XCode not know how drag-and-drop works?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand the problem.

Comment: This may be the problem: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/166383/how-to-disable-text-drag-delay

Comment: @biziclop: wow, this is so stupid. 1 sec delay! I tried and sure enough if you sit and wait for 1 second it works. I have no words. Who designed it! And btw, that solution that you linked to doesn't work anymore.

Comment: @c00000fd: It is indeed idiotic. TinkerTool should be able to fix it: http://www.bresink.com/osx/0TinkerTool/details.html says it's supported on Ventura: "Disable drag-and-drop of text in Cocoa applications or set the delay time when switching from selection mode to drag mode"